# How do you dismiss a UIPageViewController entirely?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uipageviewcontroller

How do you dismiss a UIPageViewController entirely?

I followed this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

To make an onboarding UIPageViewController for my app. It has 6 slides and works for the most part. However, my app is embedded in a Navigation controller and I just want the slides to show the walkthrough for my app. The tutorial instantiates the new UIPageViewController programmatically, but I've used interface builder for the portions of the app that were not a part of the tutorial. When I dismiss the UIPageViewController using a button that calls:

```
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil]; //these three have been used in a variety of ways
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

I return to the main page but the dots persist. The main navigation controller has a tableview as its first page and I can't access the didSelectRow method. I think the problem surrounds how the views were created (one in interface builder and one programmatically), but when I look through the docs I still can't find what I'm looking for.

I've been at this for a couple of days, so any help would be wonderful. The github is here: https://github.com/iOSDevClass/WeighFit

**This should only be the tableViewController (viewable on the left).** The thing on the right is a background picture on the UIPageViewController used for a sliding tutorial explanation. The dismiss button (partially visible) works for the UIPageViewController and the navigation bar works for the tableViewController in this state. 
[image: This should only be a tableController]

Interface builder looks like this:

[image: When 'Button' is pressed the code below runs]

Here are some notes:

```
 - superview in contentVC is currently null, how to set a superview and switch to it
 - navigation bar works in dismissed state, but the content area holds the PageContentViewController in memory
 - they both have the same storyboard
 - they both have the same window
 - root view is the same navigation controller
    - all carry only one child view controller: DayListTableViewController
 - both have the same window level and screen
 - have the same containerview
 - Day list is a UITableView and PageContent is a UIView for their views
 -what does didMoveToParentViewController subclass and what does it do?
    -UIViewController
    -In 'responding to containment events': Called after the view controller is added or removed from a container view controller.
 -is the object graph what stays in the content area?
 -views (in general) can receive touch events
 -if your nib file is not associated with a view controller, you can load the nib file contents manually using an NSBundle or UINib object, which use the data in the nib file to reconstitute your view objects.
 -there is a difference between adding a child view controller (via navigation controller) and a subview (on a UIView)
 -could tag the view to return to it later
 -convert between different coordinate systems
 -If you do not retain the view before the next event loop cycle, the view will be released.
 -there are two phantom screens to the left and right, the buttons on the phantom objects work
```

I have this code hooked up to a button I press in my initial view controller:

```
    -(void) initializeWalkthrough
    {
    //The final step is to create and initialize the UIPageViewController.
    // Create the data model
    _pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
    _pageImages = @[@"WeighFitLogo.png", @"dayList.png", @"mealRecorder.png", @"daySetup.png"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];              // We first create the PageViewController instance.
                                                                                                                            // The ID is used as reference for creating the view controller instance. To instantiate a view controller in storyboard, you can use the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method with a specific storyboard ID.
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;                                                                              // Next we specify the data source, in this case it is the class itself.

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);    //Lastly, we change the size of the page view controller and add the page controller view to the current view.

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];                        //this is the line that transitions to a new view
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];}
    #pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source  //
    /*
    We simply tell iOS that we have the total number of pages to display in the page view controller and the first page should be selected by default.
    */

    //It is a helper method that is designed to create the page content view controller on demand.  It takes in the index parameter and creates the corresponding page content controller.
- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;         //we get the current page index

    if (index == NSNotFound) {                                                         //Depending the method, we simply increase/decrease the index number and return the view controller to display.
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
    }

    //To display a page indicator, you have to tell iOS the number of pages (i.e. dots) to display in the page view controller and which page must be selected at the beginning. Add the following two methods at the end of the ViewController.m file:
    (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
    {
    return [self.pageTitles count];
    }

    (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
    {return 0;
}
```

Here is my console output when I NSLogged every relevant property I could find.

Dayslist = TableViewController

PageViewContent = UIPageViewController

The sequence of events are

1. Pressed button to run above code to initialize the UIPageViewController
2. On UIPageViewController, pressed dismiss button to dismiss UIPageViewController:

:

```
*****     DayList begin     *****
before interactions start
[self.view superview]: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x175b2960; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x175ab8f0>>
self.storyboard: <UIStoryboard: 0x1768caf0>
self.view: <UITableView: 0x17999400; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; tintColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.286275 0.376471 0.917647 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x176a0fe0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x176876f0>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 512}>
self.view.subviews: (
    "<UITableViewWrapperView: 0x1819e800; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x176a46c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1768a3a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 568}>",
    "<UIRefreshControl: 0x175afcb0; frame = (0 0; 320 60); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x175aead0>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x176a29c0; frame = (3 498.5; 314 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17674290>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x176765c0; frame = (314.5 3; 2.5 491); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x176766a0>>"
)
self.view.superview: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x175b2960; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x175ab8f0>>
self.view.layer: <CALayer: 0x176876f0>
[self.view window]: <UIWindow: 0x175a5a30; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1759e910>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1759d0e0>>
[self.view window].rootViewController: <NavigationController: 0x1819f000>
[self.view window].windowLevel: 0.000000
[self.view window].screen: <UIScreen: 0x17572430; bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x1756d380; size = 640.000000 x 1136.000000>>
[self.view window].keyWindow: 
[self.navigationController view]: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x175a9a00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1769c790>; layer = <CALayer: 0x175aa0a0>>
[self.navigationController childViewControllers]: (
    "<DayListTableViewController: 0x17690fb0>"
)
before interactions end
after interactions start
[self.view superview]: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x175b2960; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x175ab8f0>>
self.storyboard: <UIStoryboard: 0x1768caf0>
self.view: <UITableView: 0x17999400; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; tintColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.286275 0.376471 0.917647 1; tag = 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x176a0fe0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x176876f0>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 512}>
self.view.subviews: (
    "<UITableViewWrapperView: 0x1819e800; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x176a46c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1768a3a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 568}>",
    "<UIRefreshControl: 0x175afcb0; frame = (0 0; 320 60); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x175aead0>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x176a29c0; frame = (3 498.5; 314 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17674290>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x176765c0; frame = (314.5 3; 2.5 491); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x176766a0>>",
    "<_UIPageViewControllerContentView: 0x175d1b10; frame = (0 0; 320 538); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x175d1a30>>"
)
self.view.superview: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x175b2960; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x175ab8f0>>
self.view.layer: <CALayer: 0x176876f0>
[self.view window]: <UIWindow: 0x175a5a30; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1759e910>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1759d0e0>>
[self.view window].rootViewController: <NavigationController: 0x1819f000>
[self.view window].windowLevel: 0.000000
[self.view window].screen: <UIScreen: 0x17572430; bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x1756d380; size = 640.000000 x 1136.000000>>
[self.view window].keyWindow: 
[self.navigationController view]: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x175a9a00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1769c790>; layer = <CALayer: 0x175aa0a0>>
[self.navigationController childViewControllers]: (
    "<DayListTableViewController: 0x17690fb0>"
)
after interactions end
^^^^^     DayList end     ^^^^^
*****     Pageview Content begin     *****
before interactions start
[self.view superview]: <UIView: 0x176bc540; frame = (320 0; 320 501); layer = <CALayer: 0x176bc600>>
self.storyboard: <UIStoryboard: 0x1768caf0>
self.view: <UIView: 0x175b5770; frame = (0 0; 320 501); autoresize = W+H; tintColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.286275 0.376471 0.917647 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x175d3450>>
self.view.subviews: (
    "<UIImageView: 0x175894c0; frame = (16 0; 288 501); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x175d3270>>",
    "<UILabel: 0x175c17a0; frame = (76 44; 169 20.5); text = 'Over 200 Tips and Tricks'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x175c63c0>>",
    "<UIButton: 0x175a0f70; frame = (124 451; 72 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1756de70>>",
    "<_UILayoutGuide: 0x175c4d30; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x175c0c90>>",
    "<_UILayoutGuide: 0x17579bb0; frame = (0 501; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x175cb910>>"
)
self.view.superview: <UIView: 0x176bc540; frame = (320 0; 320 501); layer = <CALayer: 0x176bc600>>
self.view.layer: <CALayer: 0x175d3450>
[self.view window]: <UIWindow: 0x175a5a30; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1759e910>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1759d0e0>>
[self.view window].rootViewController: <NavigationController: 0x1819f000>
[self.view window].windowLevel: 0.000000
[self.view window].screen: <UIScreen: 0x17572430; bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x1756d380; size = 640.000000 x 1136.000000>>
[self.view window].keyWindow: 
[[self.view superview] superview]: <_UIQueuingScrollView: 0x181c0200; frame = (0 0; 320 501); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x176bb6a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x176bb280>; contentOffset: {320, 0}; contentSize: {960, 501}>
[self.navigationController view]: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x175a9a00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1769c790>; layer = <CALayer: 0x175aa0a0>>
[self.navigationController childViewControllers]: (
    "<DayListTableViewController: 0x17690fb0>"
)
before interactions end
^^^^^     Pageview Content end     ^^^^^
after interactions start
[self.view superview]: (null)
self.storyboard: <UIStoryboard: 0x1768caf0>
self.view: <UIView: 0x175b5770; frame = (-1160 -1250.5; 320 501); alpha = 0; hidden = YES; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tintColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.286275 0.376471 0.917647 1; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x175d3450>>
self.view.subviews: (
    "<UIImageView: 0x175894c0; frame = (16 0; 288 501); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x175d3270>>",
    "<UILabel: 0x175c17a0; frame = (76 44; 169 20.5); text = 'Over 200 Tips and Tricks'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x175c63c0>>",
    "<UIButton: 0x175a0f70; frame = (124 451; 72 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1756de70>>",
    "<_UILayoutGuide: 0x175c4d30; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x175c0c90>>",
    "<_UILayoutGuide: 0x17579bb0; frame = (0 501; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x175cb910>>"
)
self.view.superview: (null)
self.view.layer: <CALayer: 0x175d3450>
[self.view window]: (null)
[self.view window].rootViewController: (null)
[self.view window].windowLevel: 0.000000
[self.view window].screen: (null)
[self.view window].keyWindow: 
[[self.view superview] superview]: (null)
[self.navigationController view]: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x175a9a00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1769c790>; layer = <CALayer: 0x175aa0a0>>
[self.navigationController childViewControllers]: (
    "<DayListTableViewController: 0x17690fb0>"
)
after interactions end
```

The noted 'interactions' include:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.view];
self.view.hidden = YES;
self.view.alpha = 0.0;
self.view.tag = 2;
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.view.center = CGPointMake(-1000,-1000);

[[self.view window] resignKeyWindow];
[self.view resignFirstResponder];
[self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the 
- instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method

Comment: I just found out that the code from the tutorial makes the PageViewController the superview (it returns nil to [self.view super]), perhaps because the view Controller embedded in the navigation controller (daysVC) is made with interface builder (stored in the nib), it returns UIViewControllerWrapperView. Hmm

Comment: I don't even know if it's possible. I just read this "A page view controller manages a self-contained view hierarchy." here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3 and I see that UIPageViewController and Navigation Controller are sibling elements here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3

Comment: popViewController lives on the navigation controller. So is there a way to transition between objects? Isn't there something called toll free bridges?

Comment: The answer would be here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController

Comment: So it says "Container view controllers are often installed as root view controllers in a window (as shown in Figure 2-2), but they can also be presented modally or installed as children of other containers." here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheViewControllerHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH33-SW1

Comment: Ok, I've found out that the parent of the PageContentViewController in the UIPageViewController is the UIPageViewController and the child of the FoodDiaryVC(Embedded in Navigation Controller) is the UIPageViewController. So the question becomes how to dismiss, send to the back of stack so it doesn't show or have interactions.

Comment: NSLogging the navigation controller property in UIPageViewController returns: self.navigationController: <UINavigationController: 0x17a93a00> so it is a child of a navigation controller